# MSI 760GM-P34FX cannot use entire 3Tb drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, motherboard

Not sure what I can do about it, but I am unable to use my Seagate Desktop 3Tb drive with MSI motherboard.  It seems the motherboard only supports 2Tb for a boot drive...

and I cannot even create a secondary partition after Windows has been installed.  There is no option to do so.

is there anything I can do?

Apparently I don't have enough rep to post images, but the image I was going to post is my `Disk Management` console with Disk 0 shown with 3 partitions:

- System (Reserved) of 100Mb,
- C: of 2047.90Gb,
- and Unallocated of 746.52Gb.

When I click on Unallocated, it shows menu with New Simple Volume, and other options grayed out.

If possibly I can use another drive as OS and 3Tb as a data drive that will do fine, but in this case I don't even know if I can.

Comment: MBR is limited to 2TB. If you partitioned it using the MBR partition scheme then you can only use either the first 2TiB, or (3TB-2TiB which is about 750GiB). Solution, put the BIOS in UEFI mode, boot the windows DVD in UEFI mode. Install the OS again.

If you have an old or a badly designed BIOS then this will not work and you will need to update the BIOS or change motherboards to something which supports a non-ancient BIOS.

Comment: Keep in mind that booting to a GPT is only supported for 64-bit editions on UEFI-based systems.

Comment: gah.  I'm afraid this BIOS is not up to par.  Looking at motherboard specs I see nothing about UEFI, so I may be out of luck....  Unless I want to install some kind of a primary disk for OS, and maybe use the 3Tb for Data.  This may be my only option other than returning 3Tb disk and getting something smaller.

Answer (score 2):

If you formatted the drive using an M.B.R.P.T. (Master Boot Record Partition Table) then you will have a 2TB limit imposed. You can get around this by formatting your disk with a G.P.T. (Globally Unique Identifier Partition Table), but this requires a version of Windows capable of booting from G.P.T., and the computer to be running in U.E.F.I. (Unified Extensible Firmware Interface) mode.

You have stated in your comments that you don't believe your motherboard supports U.E.F.I., and while your motherboard is fairly new, I have not seen any mention of U.E.F.I. support in the manual ( http://dl.msi.com/download_files/mnu_exe/M7641v4.0.zip ). There is a B.I.O.S. (Basic Input Output System) update for your motherboard that adds support for drives larger than 2.2TB ( http://www.msi.com/support/mb/760GMP34_FX.html#down-bios ), but there is no documentation about how the update achieves this. I NEVER recommend installing B.I.O.S. or firmware updates unless a situation is dire, for fear of update failure.

Since your drive is a Seagate one, you might also be interested in Seagate's tools for getting around the 2TB limit on M.B.R.P.T. drives. It's essentially a special driver and an application that allows mounting the remaining space as seperate partition ( http://www.seagate.com/ca/en/support/downloads/beyond-2tb/ ) and ( http://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/docs/MB615_1102_US%282%29.pdf ). I've never used it so I don't anything beyond that.

Additional information about Windows, B.I.O.S., and the 2TB limit: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2581408

Comment: ypu could have simply said the motherboard has BIOS instead of UEFI, the rest is honestly noise